# Adding total and % data to legend in google chart

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, legend, legend-properties

Is there a way in which I can add Total count of each column for all the rows from my data to the legend on the google line chart

So by default I get something like this in google charts legends

[image]

But I want to display it like this

[image]

I am able to get all the total counts for each item on legend just want to know if there is any way I can put it as a part of the legend

I know we can control some legend properties on chart by adding a property in the options,

```
var options = {
    legend: { position: 'labeled', labeledValueText: 'none'}
}
```

I tried searching the documentation for any other property that I can add to the legend object which might help me get what I want but did not find anything in the documentation.

Comment: nothing out of the box, it may be easier to hide the legend and add a custom table beside the chart...